# SingleTap on UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I see many post dealing with the UIScrollView like in the PhotoApp, but I don't really understand them, thats why I want to reopen a post about it and have a simple solution.

What I want is to create (without IB) a simple UIViewController who will contain a UIScrollView (inside my scrollView there will be image and the scrollView will be set to pagingEnable to YES of course).
I want to be able with a simple touch of the screen to display the navigationController.navigationBar inside my UIViewController and with another touch not displaying it of course.

Can anyone show me how to implement that?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UIButton instead of UIImageView within scroll. Or add transparent button with window size before adding your image view.

Comment: thats not a bad idea I will try it, but I don't think thats the best one too and I really want to do that without using any tiers object

Comment: Unfortunately UIScrollView have a lot of side effects and restrictions so in most cases there need to implement custom workarounds like that.  
Also you can add transparent button in UIScrollView subclass.

Comment: yeah I implemented your method, thats the easiest way for the moment I think.